# Is sails.js is still in beta mode

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Is sails.js is still in beta mode as currently their latest version is 0.12.x. I would like to know if this framework is ready to be used in the real time applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it, but you will probably face to some undiscovered bugs. I don't recommend you to use it in apps for casual people, but you can start develop new app on it and wait for full version.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow,

After an in-dept investigation into sales js, yes it is still in beta.

Have a good day

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Sails.js is very much ready for production use, and I've used it in several projects myself. Though the current version is `0.12.4` - which traditionally would suggest beta state - the project has been developed and maintained since 2012, with 5747 commits, 209 contributors and 15091 stars on Github as of today.

The next major release will be `1.0`, by the way. See [roadmap](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/ROADMAP.md).